# Sort Array by Order of another Array

Tags: julia

I have

```
a = ["B", "C", "A"]
```

and

```
b = [7, 10, 5]
```

How can I sort `a` by the order of the elements of `b`?

So, to explain, the order of the elements in `b` is the indexes of the sorted elements (`[3,1,2]`). I would like to use that to do this:

```
a[[3,1,2]]
["A", "B", "C"]
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are looking for [`sortperm`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/sort/#Base.sortperm):

> `sortperm(v; alg::Algorithm=DEFAULT_UNSTABLE, lt=isless, by=identity, rev::Bool=false, order::Ordering=Forward)`
>
> Return a permutation vector `I` that puts `v[I]` in sorted order. The order is specified using the same keywords as `sort!`. The permutation is guaranteed to be stable even if the sorting algorithm is unstable, meaning that indices of equal elements appear in ascending order.

Applied to your example:

```
julia> a = ["B", "C", "A"]
3-element Array{String,1}:
 "B"
 "C"
 "A"

julia> b = [7, 10, 5]
3-element Array{Int64,1}:
  7
 10
  5

julia> perm = sortperm(b)
3-element Array{Int64,1}:
 3
 1
 2

julia> a[perm]
3-element Array{String,1}:
 "A"
 "B"
 "C"
```